# Loop and stop separate movie clips in one animation

Tags: loops, actionscript, flash-cs6

I'm creating a small flash banner ad for a school project. I have multiple layers of animated snowflakes that are all MovieClips, and at the end of the timeline I have two text items that are MovieClips which slide in. What I can't figure out is how to have the snowflakes remain on a continuous loop once the animation has ended and have the text remain on stage at it's stopped point. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Put the snowflakes into their own separate MovieClip with a Timeline, and in that new MovieClip, put something like

```
gotoAndPlay(1)
```

on the last frame.

Then drag that MovieClip onto the main timeline, so it plays within itself.

Put the text into its own separate MovieClip too, and put a

```
stop()
```

on the last frame. And drag that onto the main timeline.

Comment: New User. They might come back :)